# $scope.$on only works on first view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJS, but have run into a problem with my Ionic app. On one of my views I'm using ng-repeat to show the values from a pouchDB. However, it only works the first time I view it. If I navigate away from the view and then back it is just blank. I believe I have identified the problem to be part of the code in my controller.

My view:

```
<ion-view title="All">
  <ion-content padding="true">
    <div class="list" ng-controller="MyController">
      <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="name in names">
      {{name.name}} 
      <button class="button button-clear button-assertive" ng-click="addFav(name.name)">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-heart-outline"></i>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>      
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $ionicPopup, PouchDBListener) {
  $scope.names = [];

  $scope.addFav = function(favName) {     
      $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Favorite',
          template: favName + ' has been added',
          okText: 'OK'
      })
  }

  $scope.$on('add', function(event, name) {
      $scope.names.push(name);
  });
});
```

It seems that the $scope.$on is only run on the first view and thereby causing the view to be blank. Being new, I got the above code from a tutorial and therefore don't really have any ideas on what is causing it or how to fix it?

UPDATE:

I have a broadcast in my factory that syncs my DB:

```
app.factory('PouchDBListener', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

localDB.changes({
    continuous: true,
    onChange: function(change) {
        if (!change.deleted) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                localDB.get(change.id, function(err, doc) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('add', doc);
                    })
                });
            })
        } else {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('delete', change.id);
            });
        }
    }
});

return true;
 }]);
```

Do I need a broadcast in my controller as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `$scope.names = [];`

`$scope.$on` is an event listener, so there should be `$scope.$emit` or `$scope.$broadcast` in order to load your array.

So while loading first time some event occurs through `$scope.$emit` or `$scope.$broadcast` and it is listened with `$scope.$on`, so your array gets loaded.

I think its not happening again when your switch views and come back.

please see last comment for explanation

I just altered your plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/CZuqLzkU0wd0Soskvi2j/preview

Hope this helps !!!!!!

Comment: I have the broadcast that $cope.$on listens for in my factory - I updated my question to also show my factory. Still now sure what is wrong and what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: since `$scope.names = []`, when you switch views empty array will be initialized so in order to load that, again that event(add) need to be listened. But `$broadcast` only happens when the localDB changes. If possible, please make a **plunker** with your code.

Comment: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/ikZFUn0ZnIDNTo2gOOrs?p=preview click the all button, which will load the db values, hit back button and then the all button again. The view is now blank.

Comment: Instead of declaring the array in controller `$scope.name= []` and updating it using event listeners, just add that array to the factory and update it whenever the change occurs. I updated answer with plunker. please see answer above

Comment: Thank you, Alhuck A - Working as expected now :) I wouldn't have figured that out myself. Really appreciate your support on this. Have a great weekend!